# Assigning an accessibility identifier to an MKMapView object

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to configure snapshot for an app I'm working in, it already works in the english version but in the localized versions I don't know how to assign an accessibility identifier to a pin in the Map in MKMapView, somebody knows hows to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessibility identifiers are a great way to separate your application's language from Xcode UI Testing. The identifier comes from [`UIAccessibilityIdentification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityIdentification_Protocol/) which `UIView` already conforms to. However, neither `NSObject` nor `MKAnnotation` conform to the protocol. So you have to set that conformance yourself.

```
class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation, UIAccessibilityIdentification {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let title: String?
    var accessibilityIdentifier: String?

    init(title: String?, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}

let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.703490, -73.987770)
let annotation = Annotation(title: "BeerMenus HQ", coordinate: coordinate)
annotation.accessibilityIdentifier = "Custom Identifier"
let mapView = MKMapView()
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Then under test you can reference the annotation via `otherElements`.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let annotation = app.maps.element.otherElements["Custom Identifier"]
annotation.tap()
```